# GreyBox Overlay from Image Map

Tags: javascript, html

I have used [GreyBox](http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox) in the past to show an image overlay from an image map area tag.

```
<area shape ="circle" coords ="245,350,10" href="images/photo.jpg" onClick="return GB_showImage('Title', this.href)" />
```

but now I find that on the first click the photo is not displayed.  If I close the greybox, and click on the image map again, then the photo is displayed correctly.

Can anyone explain what is going on here please?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on the Greybox demo page either!